# Why vectors of strings of same length have different object.size?

Tags: r, memory

I was expecting that vectors of fix-length strings of same length to have same object size in R. However, `object.size` give different results for 3 such character vectors:

```
library(stringi)
x <- rep("123456", 100)
y <- c(rep("123456", 50), rep("654321", 50))

set.seed(1)
z <- stri_rand_strings(100, 6)

object.size(x)
#> 888 bytes
object.size(y)
#> 936 bytes
object.size(z)
#> 5640 bytes

object.size(sample(z, 100, replace = T))
#> 4008 bytes

object.size(sample(z, 100, replace = T))
#> 3672 bytes
```

My question is why the object size for `x`, `y` and `z` is different?

---

## Edit

If there is a global string pool, when we sample strings from existing string pool, they should have the same size. However this is not the case, see the last two examples of above code.

Comment: At a guess, it looks like [string interning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) is used, although I didn't know R did this and don't know how to check whether/how a particular vector has had interning applied.

Comment: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html (excerpt: The same issue also comes up with strings, because R has a global string pool. This means that each unique string is only stored in one place, and therefore character vectors take up less memory than you might expect..)

Comment: @Gopala, see my edit. If there is a global string pool, shouldn't 'object.size(sample(z, 100, replace = T))` alway have the same size?

Comment: @mt1022 No, because with `replace = TRUE` some strings will be repeated and others omitted, so the pool is smaller than the original and will vary dependent on the number of repeats. If you up the sample size high enough that everything gets sampled, it's consistent: `object.size(sample(z, 1000, replace = TRUE))`

Comment: @alistaire. It seems I mistaked the string pool. There is a string pool for each object, instead of a single string pool for all object, right?

Comment: Nope, it's global, but `object.size` is reporting the memory allocated to that vector, which is memory used by the elements of the string pool that pertain to that vector plus 40b overhead. For example, `pryr::object_size(z)` returns 5.6k and `pryr::object_size(sample(z, 1000, replace = TRUE))` returns 12.8k, but `pryr::object_size(sample(z, 1000, replace = TRUE), z)`, which measures the memory both together consume, returns only 13.7k. The difference between the sum and the actual amount is due to the string pool.

Comment: @alistaire. Thanks for illuminating this. I originally thought that `object.size` won't take the memory of the strings already in global string pool into account and calculate only the the net increase of memory.

Answer (score 1):

In R, the character vectors are represented as a sequence of `pointers` that refer to the individual character strings.

When we create a character vector, like you did, `x`, which gets assigned with a repeated string of length 6 (i.e. `"123456"`, such as in your case), R will allocate memory for the string `"123456"` only once and then use pointers to that string for each element of the vector.

This will make the object size of `x` to be relatively smaller, which only accounts for the memory needed to store the pointers.

On the other hand, in the second case, the character vector `y` contains two different strings, which are `"123456"` and `"654321"`, here, R will need to allocate memory for each of those two strings, separately, and then use pointers to these strings for each element of the vector.

Obviously, there will be a larger object size for `y` as compared to `x` because of this difference.

In your third case, the character vector `z`, it will contain 100 randomly generated strings, each of length 6.

These strings will be stored separately in the memory, thus, resulting into a much larger object (in size) as compared to `x` and `y`.

Let me know if this helps...